# Travel to Bermuda for non-US,CA and UK citizenship

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit-visas, airport-transfer, bermuda

I live in Iran and I am going to take a summer course in Bermuda(for one month). It seems Bermuda does not need a visa and I want to know that getting a UK transit visa will allow me to enter to Bermuda? Also, there are two kind of UK transit visa (Airside and visitor in transit), could I change my airport with the visitor in transit UK visa to catch my onward flight?

Comment: If you need to pass through border control and the departure is within 48 hours: [Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) is what you will need. See [Visa to pass through the UK in transit - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) for details.

Comment: What citizenship do you hold?

Answer (score 1):

The [Direct Airside Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa) will not allow you to pass immigration or change airports. Only some nationalities require such a visa to transit the UK airside (not passing immigration); many others can transit the UK airside without a visa.

If you need to change airports, the [Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) will allow you to pass immigration to get a hotel and/or change airports. Your onward flight must depart within 48 hours after you arrive (the UK does not operate exit immigration controls at airports; your departure is recorded for immigration purposes when your plane departs with you on board).